# jQuery Dialog - same dialog from different links

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I've been having trouble implementing the problem I've had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833008/jquery-dialog-external-links-javascript-not-working/11833134) for a few days now so I'm trying to come up with an alternative of achieving the same thing. I decided to not use an external file for the form and instead have it internally in my html file. The problem I am encountering now is the dialog only shows up Package 1 and not on Package 2.

The Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#PackageBook').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height: 400
    });

    $('#PackageBookOpen').click(function(){
        $('#PackageBook').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div id="Package1" class="packageDialog">
        <div id="order">
            <a id="PackageBookOpen" title="Package Booking" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#"><img src="images/order.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Package2" class="packageDialog">
        <div id="order">
            <a id="PackageBookOpen" title="Package Booking" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#"><img src="images/order.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="PackageBook" class="packageBookDialog" title="Package Booking">
        <form name="package" action="">
               //Form 
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You re-used `id="PackageBookOpen"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have multiple of the same Id's. Use a class selector instead e.g.

```
 $('.packageBookOpen').click(function(){
        $('#PackageBook').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

and add the class packageBookOpen to the appropriate elements.

Comment: I was having some trouble having PackageBook as an ID as well, but changing it to a class fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: That's odd what was the issue with the PackageBook  id?